# problem with drop down value in php

Tags: php

i have a drop down list which is populated dynamically from database table i.e

```
<form method=post action='dropdown.php'>
<?php
$query="SELECT DISTINCT style FROM style";
$result = mysql_query ($query);
echo "<select name=style[] size=4 value='' multiple>Choose Style</option>";
         while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)){//Array or records stored in $nt
          echo "<option value=$nt[style]>$nt[style]</option>";
           }
         echo "</select>";// Closing of list box
          mysql_close($conn);?>
<input type=submit> </form>
```

When i post the form to another page the value of dropdown after space is not shown i.e if i select (Micro Pave) from drop down list then it will only show Micro. my php code is

```
$style=$_POST['style'];
if( is_array($style)){
while (list ($key, $val) = each ($style)) {
echo $val."<br/>";
}
}
```

Comment: Open the page source. You'll be surprized.

Comment: If there is some autoincrement field in the style table, it should be used as a value instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 echo "<option value='$nt[style]'>$nt[style]</option>";
```

Missed your single quotes! :)

Comment: pure luck :) i posted the exact question a couple of weeks ago. Was the same answer, easy to miss though!

Comment: `htmlspecialchars($nt['style'], ENT_QUOTES)` should be also used

Comment: Care to read my comment above? I do understand that you have a very little experienceand never met an issue with quotes in values, but why not to read one who knows a lot more? Just READ? And also LEARN. It's not that hard.

Comment: You seem very pushy with your knowledge, yet you didn't submit an answer, you just put snarky comments on everyone elses answers. Good job

Comment: Still you prefer to discuss my person over than your answer. That's exact portrait of average SO user - greedy for stupid rep points, very weak at technlogy and always personal

Answer (score 1):

missing quotes in the option value:

```
$ntstyle = htmlspecialchars($nt['style'], ENT_QUOTES);
echo "<option value='{$ntstyle}'>".$ntstyle."</option>";
```

Comment: well I didn't notice quotes at first. anyway, there is exact answer already and with the same lack of htmlspecialchars

Comment: well i did test it before posting it. Wasn't quite sure if i had to post the entire code if the corrections, anyway thats ok will keep that in mind..

Comment: you can edit your answer so I'll be able to redo a downwote. And if you also add htmlspecialchars which ought to be here (to prevent the same problem with another symbol), I'll even upvote it

Comment: yes, just a slight note: no need to use {} braces for regular variables. it's required for $var->property and $var['key'] variables only. So, the whole string could be written in one statement, just as `echo "<option value='$ntstyle'>$ntstyle</option>";`

Comment: thanks for leting me know also do you know if there's any advantage of doing so?

Comment: as for the formatting it's just a matter of personal preference. Personally, I just prefer less typing.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT style FROM style";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo 'Choose Style
      <select name="style[]" size="4" multiple="multiple">';
while ($nt = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo '<option value="'.$nt['style'].'">'.$nt['style'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Almost right. There should be , instead of . in echo function.

Comment: It's faster and more elegant. You're not concatenating the string, just passing arguments to echo. ;) But your solution works too of course.

Comment: @Anon it's not faster, silly. You just have read some stupid article and mindlessly repeat that. It is not faster nor elegant. To be elegant there shouldn't be friggin SQL in that code nor HTML tags inside of PHP strings.

Answer (score 0):

Well for a start any attributes should be contained in double quotes.

```
echo "<option value=$nt[style]>$nt[style]</option>";
```

Should be

```
echo '<option value="'.$nt[style].'">'.$nt[style].'</option>';
```

Comment: But they are more commonly used in HTML than single.

Answer (score 0):

So many things wrong unfortunately... :(

Start with `"{$nt['style']}"` instead of just `"$nt[style]"`.
(or better yet: `echo 'Constant', $arr['item'];`)

Fix this:

`echo "<select name=style[] size=4 value='' multiple>**Choose Style</option>**;`

It's a wrong place for a label and the tag  is not open!

Also add "" to your params="" in HTML.

Comment: True, my bad. I'm used to notation $arr[item] (outside of a string) 'throwing' a notice in strict mode (undefined constant to be precise).